# Nvidia Quadro (K1100) Performance issues

Tags: drivers, nvidia, performance, proprietary, framerate

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my laptop with the following system specs:

```
 - Intel Core i7-4810MQ
 - Intel HD 4600 (integrated GPU)
 - Nvidia Quadro K1100 (2GB RVAM)
 - 24 GB RAM 
 - ubuntu-drivers --list 
        bash 
        nvidia-driver-390
        nvidia-drivers-418-server 
        xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

When using Nvidia "performance mode", the performance is terrible. When I'm using the laptop to browse the internet there are a lot of dropped frames. The FPS is about 20 and the graphics are slow. The CPU temperature is very high. It is about 70°C without opening anything, just Ubuntu is booted. It is 85°C when I open firefox.

When using Intel power-saving mode, the performance is very good while browsing but I can't use my Nvidia card.

I also tried switching to nouveau but the current GPU running is Intel HD, not Nvidia, so it's the same problem that I can't use the Nvidia card.

What should I do? Are there any other drivers?

- I installed Ubuntu with 3rd party proprietary drivers without the latest updates - When I switched to nouveau the primary GPU became intel HD, not Nvidia and I don't know how to switch it back - I have tried nvidia-drivers-390, 418, 415 - ubuntu-drivers recommends 390 for me, but the Nvidia website recommends 418, but both are bad - Thank you for editing my question
- I searched for how to know the current used GPU and it's the result (I'm using intel HD after switching to nouveau)

```bash
glxinfo -B                                                                                                                                      127 ↵
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2) (0x416)
    Version: 22.2.0
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 1536MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.6
    Max compat profile version: 4.6
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.2.0-rc1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.2.0-rc1
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 22.2.0-rc1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

Comment: nouveau is a Nvidia driver so how can it be that you're using nouveau and *not* using the Nvidia card?  Can you tell us how you installed the Nvidia drivers to begin with? Did you install Ubuntu or did someone else? Did you choose to install 3rd party proprietary drivers and download updates when asked during the guided installation? Which version of the Nvidia driver have you been using? Please edit your question.

Comment: How do you know the primary GPU became Intel when you switched to nouveau? Is this a desktop computer or a laptop? If this is a desktop computer, how is the display connected? If this is a laptop, have you reviewed the firmware/BIOS settings to make sure you don't have to select the GPU at the firmware level?

Comment: FYI different versions of Nvidia drivers won't work together and none of them will work with nouveau. You can't have these all installed on your system at the same time. It's not clear how you installed all of these different drivers. It's possible that your current inability to solve this problem could be that you have remnants of other drivers on your system. In that case this problem can't be solved without removing those remnants or reinstalling the system.

Comment: I could reinstall ubuntu to get rid of what I installed, but I don't what to do after

Comment: I don't know what you mean with select GPU at the firmware level, so if there is an article or video please share it

Comment: You'll need to consult with the laptop documentation or laptops manufacturer support if you have a laptop with "hybrid" graphics. Especially since this computer seems to have hardware from 2014.  The implementation of hybrid graphics is not consistent and wasn't common in 2014.  If the GPU needs to be selected in the firmware you'll need to figure out how to do that because in that case it's not anything you can fix in Ubuntu. I suggest reinstalling and choosing both 3rd party drivers and to install updates. This will install and use appropriate drivers, provided there is no firmware problem.

Comment: I already installed ubuntu with 3rd party drivers and selected "install updates", the driver installed automatically was nvidia-driver-390 which has the referred problem
Thank you for helping, I'll search for Hybrid graphics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The problem was not in the drivers, the Nvidia card clock was 100 Mhz and `Power Source` was a battery even if I'm using AC power shown here:
  [image: here]
- I installed `acpi` so the power source switched automatically to AC and the card clock became 705 shown here:
- [image: here]
- to fix screen tearing: `sudo xrandr --output Display_name --set TearFree on`

  - to know the Display_name use `xrandr`